# How can I change the backgroundColor of a row in a beufy datatable with a given color for each row?

Tags: vue.js, bulma, buefy

I'm new to web technologies and I'm stuck this this problem: **I would like to be able to change the color of a row dynamically.**

I tried different things with my knowledge and none worked well. I have a json with information for the table with the color code inside `(ex: #D465F2)`. I wasn't able to find a way to color the entire row in one time dynamically. I can do it with predetermined css but it's not what I need.

The only way it worked is this one:

Template:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <p class="title">logs</p>
    <b-table
      :data="loginfo"
      :sticky-header="stickyHeaders"
      height="1200px"
      :row-class="() => 'relative'"
    >
      <b-table-column v-slot="props" field="log_id" label="color">
        <div class="colored-cell" :style="{ backgroundColor: props.row.color }">
          <p>{{ props.row.color }}</p>
        </div>
      </b-table-column>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  props: {
    id: Number,
    state: Number,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loginfo: [],
      stickyHeaders: true,
      dateSearchable: false,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    id(newId) {
      this.newLog()
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async newLog() {
      await axios
        .get('http://127.0.0.2:5001/api/log?sequence=' + this.id)
        .then((response) => (this.loginfo = response.data.data))
    },
  },
}
```

Exemple of json send to the script:

```
"data": [
    {
      "color": "#15986E", 
      "log_id": 25, 
      "logged_at": "2022-05-17 16:27:00.015", 
    },
```

and this is my css:

```js
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.colored-cell {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
```

With this code I color each cell one by one but it makes the table unreadable and all broken. Everything is on top of each other. [TableBroken Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiuOX.png)

If anyone have the solution to make the table looks great again/color row dynamically or anything that can help me, another lib which allows me to change the row color dynamically.

Comment: your styles are very strange (both row and `.colored-cell`) - remove that and check if table is still broken

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `td-attrs` prop [as documented](https://buefy.org/documentation/table/#api-view)

```js
  <b-table>
      :data="loginfo"
      :sticky-header="stickyHeaders"
      height="1200px"
    >
      <b-table-column v-slot="props" field="log_id" label="color" :td-attrs="columnTdAttrs">     
        {{ props.row.color }}
      </b-table-column>
    </b-table>
  </div>
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    columnTdAttrs(row, column) {
      return {
        style: {
          backgroundColor: row.color
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: I tried to use it directly on b-table and it didn't work, I just used it the wrong way. Atleast now it works ! Thank you so much